# Need help to keep cell blank when J8 blank

Tags: excel, if-statement

Need help to keep cell blank when J8 blank

=IF(J8="Complete","Pass",IF(J8="In-Process","Incomplete","NA"))

Comment: Wrap your `IF` with `ISBLANK` function. Here: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-isblank-function This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Nest another layer of if:
=IF(J8="","",your_original_if)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2019 / 365 updated

Use `IFS` function

```
=IFS(J8="Complete","Pass",J8="In-Process","Incomplete",J8="","",TRUE,"NA")
```

Comment: If it works, remember to mark the answer so others may find it too